# Basic equivalence of hyperbolic functions expressions

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

Given an analytic result from solving an equation, we have the result:

$$\frac{1-\operatorname{cosh}(L)}{\operatorname{sinh}(L)} \operatorname{cosh}(x) + \operatorname{sinh}(x).$$

This can be shown to be equivalent (e.g. with Mathematica) to the expression:

$$\frac{\operatorname{sinh}\left(x-\frac{L}{2}\right)}{\operatorname{cosh}\left(\frac{L}{2}\right)}.$$

Despite this just being a simple manipulation of hyperbolic identities, I cannot reach the latter expression from the first. Any advice/approach gratefully appreciated.

Mathematica finds an intermediate stage to be:

$$\operatorname{sinh}\left(x\right) - \operatorname{cosh}\left(x\right)\operatorname{tanh}\left(\frac{L}{2}\right).$$

Again, I can't see how to obtain this from the first result. Maybe I need some more coffee... I have tried using the double angle formulas for sinh and cosh, inappropriately squaring etc - I am not sure how to proceed from here! I am completely happy with the equivalence, but just would like to derive it on paper!

Comment: This gets you from the original to *Mathematica*'s intermediate step: $$1-\cosh(L)=-2\sinh^2(L/2) \qquad\qquad \sinh L = 2\sinh(L/2)\cosh(L/2)$$ although I wouldn't bother writing $\sinh/\cosh$ as $\tanh$, since the next step would be just to write everything over a common denominator of $\cosh(L/2)$.

Comment: Not sure why this took me more than 5 minutes after all this... result falls out instantly after using this step with another identity (for anybody else's future reference, $\operatorname{sinh}(x-y) = \operatorname{sinh}(x)\operatorname{cosh}(y) - \operatorname{sinh}(y)\operatorname{cosh}(x)$). Thanks @Blue. Feel free to write this as an answer and I'll accept it (so trivial it's almost barely worth the effort though!)

Comment: Write your own answer so that we can upvote your success. :)

Comment: Not so sure my blindness to secondary school maths is to be celebrated here! Thanks for your help regardless :)